# Automatically print a PDF (as a byte[])

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

Is there a way that I can automatically print a PDF (in `byte[]` format, the file does **not** exist on the disk) to a given printer? The only solutions I've found utilize PdfSharp, which can only print from a file (because it just invokes Adobe Reader).

Is there any other way to do this, or am I stuck writing a temporary file to the disk and printing with PdfSharp/Adobe?

Comment: Can you write the filestream in to temporary location and use PdfSharp or Adobe? Once the pdf is generated delete the temporary file.

Comment: @Kiru I'm thinking that's my only viable option right now, and I'm experimenting with it as we speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up writing the file to disk in a temporary folder and using [CLPrint](http://www.commandlinepdf.com/).

Answer (score -1):

I think PdfSharp will do your need. I can see this in their code

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new PDF document using the specified stream.
/// To open an existing PDF file, use the PdfReader class.
/// </summary>
public PdfDocument(Stream outputStream)
```

Comment: You can't print from that object. The PDF Print functions in PdfSharp take a filename, not a PDF object. - http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PrintPdfFile-sample.ashx